# Why do I get a naked top level expression when I add a type description to my main function?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to run my main file and it says

```
Parse error: naked expression at top level
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
```

Here's my related code

```
module Main where  
import System.IO

import System.Environment

main ∷ IO ()

main = do
```

Comment: `do` _something_ in it.

Comment: Is that ∷ character actually allowed?

Comment: yea I left out what the do was doing I didnt think it was needed ?

Answer (score 7):

You must enable the `UnicodeSyntax` extension to use `∷`. Try `{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}` at the top of your file or using two colons like `main :: IO ()`.

Comment: but I did use two colons?

Comment: @octoCat Not in the code you posted. You used a special 4-dots Unicode character instead of two colons.